# How can I anchor a rubber sheet that will be stretched?

Tags: fluid, shear, elastic-modulus, seals

I am designing a cylindrical container that will be filled with water. One end of the container will be solid with flow port and the other end will be a 3mm rubber sheet. I want to oscillate the volume of the container by pushing and pulling the rubber sheet. My main concerns are preventing leaks and making sure the rubber sheet does not tear over thousands of actuations. My current design is:

[image: Layout]

[image: Dimensions]

Here are the details of my rubber sheet:

[image]

My machinist expressed concern that the current design would shear the rubber sheet too much and cause early failure. I am unsure how to even approach this design challenge. Current design was created with some trial and error and 3d printed physical testing. Sandwiching the rubber between flat surfaces did not hold the sheet in place well enough. I am unsure what to even look up to find the right calculations for this application. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider some inspiration from diaphragm valves, which do something similar:
[image: Diaphragm valve]

[Image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaphragm_valve]

Additionally, to prevent damaging the rubber sheet over many actuation cycles, I could imagine building a chamber on the other side (like where the yellow sort of plunger sits in the image) and working with pressured air there. This way you might be able to move the rubber sheet in a more gentle way than for example mechanically.